# Argument of type 'const char*' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char*'

Tags: c++, arrays, char, copy, constants

In an operator overloading function I am using another function that copys an array. But when i call the function arrayCopy() I receive an error stating:

Argument of type 'const char*' is incompatible with parameter of type 'char*'.

Any reasons and solution to fix this problem?

```
class InfinateInteger {
public:
    InfinateInteger();
    InfinateInteger(char c[]);
    int* digitBreakDown(int c);
    int digitLength(int c);
    void intConversion(char stringArray[], int convertArray[], int size, int printQ);
    void arrayCopy(char originalArray[], char copyArray[], int size);

    const InfinateInteger operator +(const InfinateInteger& sec);    
    char * getIntString(); //getters
    int getDigitL();

    void setIntString(char newStr[]); //setters
    void setDigitL(int length);

private:
    char intString[1000000];
    int posNeg = 1; //if pos ==1 if neg ==0
    int digitL = 0;
};

const InfinateInteger InfinateInteger:: operator +(const InfinateInteger& sec) { 
//function in which error is occurring
    char str1[1000000];
    arrayCopy(intString, str1, getDigitL());
    char str2[1000000];
    arrayCopy(sec.intString, str2, getDigitL()); //<--line where error occurs!!!!!
    return InfinateInteger();
}

void InfinateInteger::arrayCopy(char originalArray[], char copyArray[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        copyArray[i] = originalArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `infinite`, not `infinate`. `sec` is const in your methods, what do you think the actual type of `sec.intString` is within that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that calls `arrayCopy` is defined like this:

```
const InfinateInteger InfinateInteger:: operator +(const InfinateInteger& sec) {
```

You can see that `sec` is qualified as `const`, which means that also `sec.intString` is `const`.

`arrayCopy` on the other hand is defined as

```
void InfinateInteger::arrayCopy(char originalArray[], char copyArray[], int size) {
```

`originalArray` is not `const`, this is why you get an error.

Change `arrayCopy` to

```
void InfinateInteger::arrayCopy(const char originalArray[], char copyArray[], int size) {
```